# How to properly close an alert box javafx

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create an alert box type window that is like a user registration panel. Now when I close the window using the top-right button (I do not have a cancel/close button implemented) and re-open it there's this error that pops up:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set modality once stage has been set visible
at javafx.stage.Stage.initModality(Stage.java:525)
at elibraryserver.NewStudentController.initRegister(NewStudentController.java:150)
at elibraryserver.serverController.addStudentButtonAction(serverController.java:71)
... 53 more
```

I do not understand since I closed the window shouldn't it reset and open another one? What I can see from the error is that it thinks the window is still open. Or am I wrong?

Here is the code for the stage:

```
public void initRegister() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("newStudent.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();

    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    registerStage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - registerStage.getWidth()) / 2);
    registerStage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - registerStage.getHeight()) / 2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    registerStage.setScene(scene);
    registerStage.setTitle("Register Student");
    registerStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    registerStage.showAndWait();
}

public void addStudentButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    NewStudentController nsc = new NewStudentController();
    nsc.initRegister();
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code so that we can better understand the problem

Comment: Posted the code.

Comment: Where do you create this variable?  registerStage?  Move the registerStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); to that location, rather than in the show.  Since you have initialized it already once it's hidden, it's still referenced and you can't change that.  Or move the Stage registerStage = new Stage(); to the initRegister() method - in that case a reference won't hang around.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your issue is I think it is because you are not creating a new stage when you initialize your new window

Here is some example code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button button = new Button("Open Test window");
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                openAction();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openAction() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Test.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Register Student");
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

testFXML Controller

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestFXMLController implements Initializable{
    public ColorPicker colorPicker;
    public VBox vBox;



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        colorPicker.setOnAction(event -> {
            Paint fill = colorPicker.getValue();
            BackgroundFill backgroundFill =
                    new BackgroundFill(fill,
                            CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                            Insets.EMPTY);
            Background background = new Background(backgroundFill);
            vBox.setBackground(background);
        });
    }
}
```

Test.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox fx:id="vBox" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="TestFXMLController">
   <children>
      <ColorPicker fx:id="colorPicker" opacity="0.5" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```